# Prevent keyboard dismiss React Native inside Modal

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

I have a textinput at the bottom of a screen, that expands into a larger section with some options when pressed. `bottomHeight` and `height` are increased when the keyboard opens.

When one of these pre-defined `tags` in the extra container is pressed, I do not want to close the keyboard but I can't make it work and could use some help.

I have wrapped the `textinput` in a scrollview to try and use `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` and `keyboardDismissMode` as suggested elsewhere but its not working.

There are no parent ScrollViews, ListViews or FlatLists to update however this component is inside `Modal` which is wrapped by `SafeAreaView`

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: this.props.bottomHeight, left: 0, right: 0, height: this.props.height }}>

// not sure if I need this inner scrollview, ideally it should just be a view
    <ScrollView style={this._computeBottomContainer()} keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" keyboardDismissMode="on-drag">
        <TextInput
            style={styles.filter}
            placeholder="Type to filter tags"
            onChangeText={(text) => this.props.suggestTags(text)}
            selectionColor="black"
            blurOnSubmit={false}
        />

        { this.props.keyboardOpen &&
            <View style={styles.tagsOuterContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.suggest}>Suggested tags: {this.props.suggestedTags.length}</Text>

                <View style={styles.tagsInnerContainer}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.props.suggestedTags}
                        horizontal={true}
                        renderItem={this.renderTag}
                        keyExtractor={( {item}, index) => item + index}
                        keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
                        keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        }
    </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: Can you share a snack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Towards the root of my app, I have a `<Swiper />` element which is basically a ScrollView. Adding `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"` to the Swiper as props solved my issue

Comment: I can't find Swiper component in react native, where did you get it?

Comment: I added it myself, its a part of my app. I solved this issue by looking at my app from Root component down, somewhere there was a swiper/scroll where I had to handle the click